# Rails code working with sqlite but fails on heroku with postgres

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rails-postgresql, heroku-postgres

Can any one suggest why the following query might be raising error:

```
TypeError: can't dump anonymous class Class: INSERT INTO "emails" ("content", "created_at", "email_from", "email_to", "filter_id", "filter_property_id", "if_processed", "merchant_id", "message_id", "sent_at", "subject", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13) RETURNING "id"
```

I am using active record method to create the record and it works locally fine with sqlite. But after I push it to heroku  I am getting this error.

I am currently developing on windows and getting to run postgres is quite tricky I guess which requires  installing cygwin, that is the reason why I am not developing with postgres locally.

Comment: this is why people say to develop on the same environment you deploy to.

Comment: Can you post your create action?  There are some variations in syntax between postgres and mysql